# Scrape table returns None

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape a simple table but I can't do it because the soup.find returns None. I have all the code done but the base is incorrect at the moment.

My code is the following:

```
url = 'https://rfef.es/es/competiciones/primera-federacion'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(page.text, 'lxml')

table1 = soup.find("div", id="tab-pane active")

headers = []
for i in table1.find_all("th"):
 title = i.text
 headers.append(title)


df = pd.DataFrame(columns = headers)

for j in table1.find_all("tr")[1:]:
 row_data = j.find_all("td")
 row = [i.text for i in row_data]
 length = len(df)
 df.loc[length] = row
```

This is the inspect:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data is loaded from external URL (you should see this url in web developer tools in your browser). To load it to pandas dataframe you can use this example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://rfef.es/es/competiciones/primera-federacion'
api_url='https://rfef.es/es/api/{a}/{b}/{c}?source=besoccer'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')
a, b, c = soup.select_one('.current-round')['value'].split('-')

df = pd.read_html(requests.get(api_url.format(a=a, b=b, c=c)).text)[0].loc[:, 'Equipo':]
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                         Equipo   P   J   G   E  P.1  GF  GC
0                    CD Eldense  51  26  15   6    5  36  17
1                 SD Amorebieta  44  26  12   8    6  36  24
2                  CD Castellón  44  26  12   8    6  35  23
3                Real Murcia CF  42  26  11   9    6  31  21
4   Real Sociedad de Fútbol "B"  41  26  10  11    5  35  26
5                   SD Logroñés  39  26  10   9    7  31  29
6          FC Barcelona Atlètic  39  26  10   9    7  31  29
7          CD Numancia de Soria  38  26  10   8    8  25  22
8                   UE Cornellà  36  26   9   9    8  25  27
9     Club Atlético Osasuna "B"  35  26  10   5   11  28  29
10       Gimnàstic de Tarragona  34  26   9   7   10  25  35
11                 CF Intercity  32  26   8   8   10  32  29
12                  CD Alcoyano  32  26   7  11    8  22  25
13                  CF La Nucía  31  26   6  13    7  26  31
14               CE Sabadell FC  30  25   8   6   11  24  31
15              Real Unión Club  30  26   8   6   12  25  33
16         CD Atlético Baleares  26  26   5  11   10  25  29
17                  UD Logroñés  25  25   5  10   10  21  24
18                 CD Calahorra  22  26   4  10   12  20  33
19            Athletic Club "B"  20  26   4   8   14  20  36
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you want the `div` with `class="tab-pane active"`, but you are searching by `id`. Try `table1 = soup.find("div", id="classificacion")`.

Comment: I tried this and continue returning None

table_div = soup.find('div' , {'id': 'clasificacion'})
table = table_div.find_all('tr')